# Creating multiple foreign keys in SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
/* DROP TABLE STATEMENTS*/
DROP TABLE BUILDING CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
DROP TABLE ROOM CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
DROP TABLE SPEAKER CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
DROP TABLE CONFERENCESESSION CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;

/* CREATE TABLE STATEMENTS*/
CREATE TABLE BUILDING(
BUILDINGNO CHAR(2),
BUILDINGWING VARCHAR2(15),
BUILDINGLANE VARCHAR2(15),
CONSTRAINT BUILDING_PK PRIMARY KEY(BUILDINGNO));

CREATE TABLE ROOM(
BUILDINGNO CHAR(2) ,
ROOMNO CHAR(2),
ROOMCAPACITY NUMBER(3), 
CONSTRAINT ROOM_PK PRIMARY KEY(BUILDINGNO, ROOMNO));

CREATE TABLE SPEAKER(
SPEAKERID CHAR(2),
SPEAKERNAME VARCHAR2(20),
SPEAKERADDRESS VARCHAR2(50),
SPEAKERPHONE CHAR(12),
CONSTRAINT SPEAKER_PK PRIMARY KEY(SPEAKERID));

CREATE TABLE CONFERENCESESSION(
SESSIONID CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
BUILDINGNO CHAR(2) REFERENCES BUILDING(BUILDINGNO),
ROOMNO CHAR(2) REFERENCES ROOM(ROOMNO),
SPEAKERID CHAR(2) REFERENCES SPEAKER(SPEAKERID),
SESSIONDATE DATE,
SESSIONPRICE NUMBER(4, 2));
```

In the last table, I am supposed to have one PK (SessionID) and 3 Foreign Keys(BuildingNo, RoomNo, SpeakerID), When i try to do this i get no matching primary keys??
Any help please? Thanks!!

Comment: fk (BuildingNo, RoomNo) references ROOM

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: because you have given foriegnkey ROOMNO CHAR(2) REFERENCES ROOM(ROOMNO),
but in table Room dont have Primary key to (ROOMNO).
You have given composite primary key not to signle column.

Comment: You already posted this morning and somebody replied and you accepted the answer. what more do you need ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
CREATE   TABLE CONFERENCESESSION
(
   SESSIONID      CHAR (4) PRIMARY KEY,
   BUILDINGNO     CHAR (2)    ,
   ROOMNO         CHAR (2)    ,
   SPEAKERID      CHAR (2)    ,
   SESSIONDATE    DATE,
   SESSIONPRICE   NUMBER (4, 2),
   CONSTRAINT fk_blding  FOREIGN KEY (BUILDINGNO) REFERENCES BUILDING (BUILDINGNO),
   CONSTRAINT fk_roomno FOREIGN KEY  (BUILDINGNO,ROOMNO)REFERENCES ROOM (BUILDINGNO,ROOMNO),
   CONSTRAINT fk_spkr_id FOREIGN KEY (SPEAKERID)  REFERENCES SPEAKER (SPEAKERID)
);
```

Comment: Thanks!! Helped me understand what i was doing wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add this syntax for the 3 columns:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_supplier
FOREIGN KEY (column1)
REFERENCES parent_table (column1)
```

Make sure to give the constraint a name too

E.G.

```
 constraint (Build_No)
 Foreign key (BUILDINGNO) 
 REFERENCES BUILDING(BUILDINGNO)
```

Make sure that you actually declare the field with its data type as well

```
CREATE TABLE CONFERENCESESSION
( product_id numeric(10) not null,
supplier_id numeric(10) not null,
BUILDINGNO CHAR(2),            <--- declared here
constraint (Build_No)
Foreign key (BUILDINGNO) 
REFERENCES BUILDING(BUILDINGNO)
);
```

Then just repeat this for the other foreign key columns too

Comment: Thanks!!! Your explanation helps a lot, wont make this mistake again!!